# Firestore: Query collection using “where” and only retrieve document IDs

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to query a firestore documents collection and want only retrieve the document ids with [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), to save **costs for reading all documents**.
As far as I understand it, the following code is retrieving all documents too and is causing read ops on all documents, no matter if I use `doc.data()` or not. Am I right?

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true).onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id);
  }
});
```

So in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) it is stated:

> For queries other than document reads, such as a request for a list of
>   collection IDs, you are billed for one document read.

Is there a way with angularfire2 to query a collection and retrieve only the document IDs?

Or is there an other way than using angularfire2?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible in any environment.

Comment: @DougStevenson Seems like a missing feature. That means, at the moment I have to download all documents although I only need the ids.

Comment: In the Admin SDKs you can do a projection and only download the fields you need (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488797/get-only-documents-names-in-firestore, although I only mention the REST API there). But it will still be charged as N document reads, since reading a document's ID requires accessing that document.

Comment: If you have a feature request, please describe your use case here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson Done.

Comment: Thank you, your feedback matters.