# List firestore collection ids filtered by criteria

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

In Go package for firestore I can easily get list of IDs by doing something like

```golang
client.Collection("mycollection").DocumentRefs()
```

with query I can easily filter documents before I can iterate over them

```golang
client.Collection("mycollection").Where("x", "==", "y").Documents()
```

But `Query` seems to be missing an option to get just the `.DocumentRefs()` is there some way to get list of DocumentRefs matching specific query without actually fetching all the matching Documents (incuring read costs for each)?

The bottom line is that after I apply the filtering logic to get constrained list of doc IDs I want to run additional regex based filtering on the values of the IDs, and the list of filtered IDs is my final result, no need fr fetching docs.

Comment: I agree with Doug Stevensons's answer but if you want more info regarding the code you can check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) doc.

Comment: I had asked a similar question 3 years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880839/firestore-query-collection-using-where-and-only-retrieve-document-ids Doug then asked me to make a feature request. I did so. Maybe you should do the same? Can't believe we are the only ones with such a use case. Even though I cache all documents at the client, I still have to reload all documents with each query. What a waste. Here the link for feature requests: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features

Answer (score 2):

Firestore queries always return the entire contents of every matching document.  There are no "light" queries that just return document IDs or references.  This is the case for all provided Firestore SDKs, not just go.

In general, it's advisable *not* to store data in the ID of a document for the purpose of filtering.  Your use case will work better if you're able to precompute the conditions where a document should match, and put that data in a field of the document.  It should be noted also that Firestore doesn't support regex type queries, as those do not scale massively as Firestore requires.

Comment: Do you see any chance that this "feature" will come? As I described, It makes no sense to download all documents, if you have them already in cache. As far as I understand databases, if i query an index, there is no need to download documents. This is more like a feature of your API.